# Selenium: Get current value from drop-down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium, selectedvalue

I'm trying to find a simple Selenium call to grab the current option from a select drop-down list.  I'm aware there are calls which grab all the values in a list but I wish to know which option is currently selected.  Apologies if this is trivial but google and Selenium IDE didn't help me.  Thanks.

Comment: getSelectedValue() seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the getSelected* commands to return the ID, index, or label of the selected item. Below is quoted from the Selenium Reference:

---

**storeSelectedId ( selectLocator, variableName )**
Gets option element ID for selected option in the specified select element.

*Arguments:*

- selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
- variableName - the name of a variable in which the result is to be stored.

*Returns:*  the selected option ID in the specified select drop-down

---

**storeSelectedIndex ( selectLocator, variableName )**
Gets option index (option number, starting at 0) for selected option in the specified select element.

*Arguments:*

- selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
- variableName - the name of a variable in which the result is to be stored.

*Returns:* the selected option index in the specified select drop-down

---

**storeSelectedLabel ( selectLocator, variableName )**
Gets option label (visible text) for selected option in the specified select element.

*Arguments:*

- selectLocator - an element locator identifying a drop-down menu
- variableName - the name of a variable in which the result is to be stored.

*Returns:* the selected option label in the specified select drop-down

Comment: Also, if you're just looking to verify/assert the value, there's a companion verifySelectedLabel command.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `storeSelectedValue` or `getSelectedValue`

**JUNIT**

```
String value = selenium.getSelectedValue(selectLocator)
```

**Selenium Action**

```
storeSelectedValue ( selectLocator, variableName )
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a link to practice such things:

"https://letskodeit.teachable.com/p/practice"

there's a "Select Class Example"

1.in this test first it clicks on "Honda" in the dropdown menu
2. then extracts the select-tag as parent of the option-tag "Honda" 
3. then converts it to Select object
4. then i uses the getFirstSelectedOption() to compare it with the expected value "Honda.

```java
    @Test
    public void selectTagDemo() {
        WebElement hondaElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value=\"honda\"]"));
        hondaElement.click();

        WebElement selectCarWebElement = hondaElement.findElement(By.xpath("//parent::select"));
        Select selectCar = new Select(selectCarWebElement);
        Assert.assertEquals(selectCar.getFirstSelectedOption().getText(), "Honda");
    }
```

if you need the whole Test class comment below